# LWC debugging and using console.log() affects behavior of my app

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a search app with 3 lightning-input fields with an onchange handler.
This onchange handler behaves differently when I trace its behavior with a console.log() command

HTML view :

```
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                <lightning-input label='Search by legalid'
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Legalid ...'
                    data-clause='legalid'
                    onfocus={handleFocus}
                    onchange={handleChange}
                    value={fpsLegalId}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                <lightning-input label='Search by customer'
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Customer identifier (phone, email, identifier) ...'
                    data-clause='customer'
                    onfocus={handleFocus}
                    onchange={handleChange}
                    value={customerIdentifier}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>

            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                <lightning-input label='Search by plate'
                    type="text"
                    placeholder='Plate ...'
                    data-clause='vehicle'
                    onfocus={handleFocus}
                    onchange={handleChange}
                    value={vehiclePlate}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
            
            <!-- BUTTON -->
            <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
                <lightning-button
                    label='Search'
                    variant='brand'
                    disabled={isDisabled}
                    onclick={handleButtonClick}>
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
```

Javascript :

```
    fpsLegalId
    vehiclePlate
    customerIdentifier

    handleChange(event) {
        const clause = event.target.dataset?.clause
        const value = event.target.value

        console.log('### Search2 handleChange : input', clause, value)

        this.fpsLegalId =         (clause == 'legalid'  ? value : this.fpsLegalId)
        this.customerIdentifier = (clause == 'customer' ? value : this.customerIdentifier)
        this.vehiclePlate =       (clause == 'vehicle'  ? value : this.vehiclePlate)

        console.log('### Search2 handleChange : res', this.fpsLegalId, this.customerIdentifier, this.vehiclePlate)
}
```

Sample output (correct) :

```
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : input – "vehicle" – "a"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – "a"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : input – "vehicle" – "ab"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – "ab"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : input – "vehicle" – "ab1"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – "ab1"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : input – "vehicle" – "ab12"
[Log] ### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – "ab12"
```

This is OK.

**My Issue**

When I comment out the first console.log()

```
//console.log('### Search2 handleChange : ', clause, value)
```

this all stops working and the output is :

```
### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – ""
### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – ""
### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – ""
### Search2 handleChange : res – "" – "" – ""
```

The values of clause and value seem to be affected by the presence/absence of the console.log()
Why ???

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any reason why this should happen, but you should be able to just:

```
handleChange(event) {
  let clause = event.target.dataset.clause;
  let value = event.target.value;
  this[clause] = value;
  console.log('Inputs: ', clause, value);
}
```

You'll want to change the clause values to match the property names.

[Example code here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/KEAFvVP9RVSI089Pzxk5/src/app.html).

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the reason but if you annotate your vars as @track works correctly, I mean...:

@track fpsLegalId
@track vehiclePlate
@track customerIdentifier

Comment: `@track` isn't required for simple variables any longer, see [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_track.htm&type=5&release=224).

Comment: I know, but I tested it and the console log shows the correct values using @track

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks